# Azure Database database is slow when locally debugging in VS 2022

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, visual-studio-2022, ef-core-2.1

I'm working on an issue with my team where we are using Azure SQL Database as a service.

In one example:

- Connecting to azure database via azure app service: call takes 350 ms
- Connecting to azure database via VS 2022 on our work computers: call takes 2.5 seconds
- Connecting to a bacpac database (from the azure database) locally on sql server on our work computers: call takes 350 milliseconds

Things we have done:

- Change the pricing tier from elastic pool to Standard S2: 50 DTUs -> still the same slowness
- Changed the location of the azure database
- Optimized some of the calls (helps, but we still see a big difference between local db and azure database)

We believe it could have something to do with the overall specific call to the server where we are making X calls to the database and opening a connection for each one?

Still doesn't seem to make sense of why it works so fast locally, but then when we connect to the azure database while developing it is so slow.

Also, it seems that this USE to not be the issue. We thought maybe a change in our work VPN could have caused it, but we've tested off the VPN and the issue still is slow connecting to the azure database.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is this just the connect part - just the first connection to the database? not running queries? How long does it take to connect from SSMS or Azure Data Studio? Note that the App Service is likely connecting via Azure backbone. I suggest briefly pushing the size up to say 8 vCores just to rule that out. (50 DTU's is till pretty tiny)

Comment: Troubleshooting connection performance is very different to troubleshooting query performance so you need to isolate which one is the issue. It really sounds like a network thing. I've seen network setups where you VPN into Azure but then the network path takes you out of Azure back to on prem where it then goes back out to Azure again through a proxy. I think you probably need to get a network person to trace the route from on prem to Azure SQL.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: SSMS connects fast from the same computer that is seeing slowness on certain calls from our local debug in VS2022 when connecting to the azure database as a service. So we think it might be 1 call that hits a bunch of our local API calls (not a web api) and all of those local API calls are connecting each time? Therefore it is slow on the Azure end.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: We think it is the amount of `await` calls we have within the specific call to the server to do X. On calls that just have 1 `await` call, it seems to be fine. It is still kinda weird the difference from local db on local sql server to azure db on azure sql server as a service. I mean I think you would expect some latency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

The issue was tied to our company work VPN.

A split-tunnel was setup to resolve the issue for the workstation to azure db traffic. (It is not evaluated via the VPN network now).